# Performance-Load testing for with HTTP post apis mapped to eventhubs

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, stress-testing

We have an application which has HTTP Triggers associated with Eventhubs which means it has the capability to accept multiple HTTP requests /sec => more than 1 million/sec requests. It can take request from multiple API HTTP post requests. We are looking to test this application. Jmeter open supports multiple APIs but its not scalable to have 1 million requests/sec.
Are there any tools which support the event hub testing for such a Load?

Answer (score 0):

Even the fastest load testing tool can achieve ~65K RPS because of the PORT limit. You can use a commercial solution or you can build your own distributed load testing infra. Locust and JMeter have distributed load testing support. But they are the poorest ones in terms of performance. So you will need lots of machines.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "not scalable to have 1 million requests/sec."? JMeter can kick off as many as [2147483647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647) threads and whether you can have million request per second will depend mainly on your application response time (see   article for more details)

Of course you need to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html).

If you don't have a machine which is powerful enough to generate 1 million requests per second be aware that you can [run JMeter in distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html) so the load would come from several machines.